# Trying to make a structure, won't let me input a string

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char

I'm trying to make a structure with the three variables int age, int siblings, and `char[]` hometown but it's not letting me insert the hometown string when the program is run. The integers work properly but it'll just skip right over the array and leave it blank. I've tried using gets and `fgets` but nothing seems to be working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    struct person{
        int age;
        int s;
        char hometown[20];
    }p;

    printf("Age: ");
    scanf("%d",&p.age); 

    printf("Siblings: ");
    scanf("%d",&p.s);

    printf("Hometown: \n");
    fgets(p.hometown, 20, stdin);   

    printf("Age \t Siblings \t Hometown\n");
    printf("%d   \t %d        \t        %s\n",p.age,p.s,p.hometown);
}
```

Comment: and how do you enter the data?

Comment: Mixing `scanf()` with `fgets()` --> no-no.  `fgets()` simple consumed the left over `'\n'` from the prior `scanf("%d",&p.s);`  Many dupes on this one/

Comment: What chux said. You can fix this quickly by adding a space after `%d`, like this: `scanf("%d ",&p.s);`

Comment: hmm yeah should close as a dupe because of the prompts

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be helping. I just tried it again with your edit and it's receiving data but not printing the "Hometown" prompt.

Comment: `fgets(p.hometown, 20, stdin);` --> `scanf(" %19[^\n]%*1[\n]", p.hometown)` is a cheap - non-elegant fix.  Better to read all with `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

The local variable might already contains garbage.

Try to memset before you use for string,
So that proper null will be terminated.

Try to acquire your input with following scan(%s,  p.hometown);

For strings no need of & for collecting the string.

If you still face the issue, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it :).

Comment: `scan(%s, p.hometown);` will not work for town names that contains a space - which is quite common.  Neither does that protect against buffer overflow.

Comment: I would use %.20s as well to be sure if you have a full 20 characters it doesn't overrun into garbage land.

Answer (score 0):

This also works for town names that contains a space and is protected against buffer overflow too.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define HOMETOWN_SIZE 20

int main(){
    struct person {
        int age;
        int s;
        char hometown[HOMETOWN_SIZE + 1]; //+ 1 for terminating null character
    } p;

    printf("Age: ");
    scanf("%d", &p.age);

    printf("Siblings: ");
    scanf("%d", &p.s);

    printf("Hometown: \n");
    getchar(); //just for consume new line from previous scanf
    fgets(p.hometown, HOMETOWN_SIZE + 1, stdin); //fgets reads n-1 characters

    //don't want new line in hometown name
    if (p.hometown[strlen(p.hometown) - 1] == '\n')
        p.hometown[strlen(p.hometown) - 1] = '\0';

    printf("Age \t Siblings \t Hometown\n");
    printf("%d   \t %d        \t        %s\n", p.age, p.s, p.hometown);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the Buffer memory before taking character array input
like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
 struct person{
    int age;
    int s;
    char hometown[20];
}p;

printf("Age: ");
scanf("%d",&p.age);

printf("Siblings: ");
scanf("%d",&p.s);
printf("Hometown: \n");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(p.hometown, 20, stdin);

printf("Age \t Siblings \t Hometown\n");
printf("%d   \t %d        \t        %s\n",p.age,p.s,p.hometown);
}
```